# Access Violation in std::pair

Tags: c++, stl

I have an application which is trying to populate a pair. Out of nowhere the application crashes.

The Windbg analysis on the crash dump suggests:

> PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  INVALID_POINTER_READ
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  INVALID_POINTER_READ
>
> STACK_TEXT:
>   0389f1dc EPFilter32!`std::vector<std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int> > >::size+0xc`
>
> INVALID_POINTER_READ_c0000005_Test.DLL!`std::vector_std::pair_unsigned_int,
>   unsigned_int_,std::allocator_std::pair_unsigned_int,unsigned_int_____::size`

Following is the code snap in the code where it fails:

```
for (unsigned i1 = 0;  i1 < size1;  ++i1)
{
    for (unsigned i2 = 0;  i2 < size2;  ++i2)
    {
      const branch_info& b1 =  en1.m_branches[i1];   //Exception here :crash 
      const branch_info& b2 =  en2.m_branches[i2];
    }
}
```

where `branch_info` is `std::pair<unsigned int,unsigned int>`
and the `en1.m_branches[i1]` fetches me a pair value.

Comment: There's not really enough info here to diagnose the problem... can you post some more of the code around the line that's crashing?

Comment: So the crash seems to be occurring out of the blue?  As in sometimes the for loops complete but other times it doesn't because of the crash?

Answer (score 4):

Probably the `i1` index is out of the bounds of the `en1.m_branches` vector.

Why don't you use `en1.m_branches.size()` in your loop condition? This would make sure you use indexes inside the correct bounds.

Comment: yeah but thats not consistent

Comment: @sameer not consistent with what?